# How does the net vertical force equation for a non-relativistic string derived?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, notation, string, approximations

In the following image from *"A first course in string theory"*, we get the net vertical force of a string, dFv. While I understand the first equation, I don't understand how the second equation is derived. No further explanation is given in in the textbook as to how the second equation is derived, and I also don't understand what the symbol ≃ means. I did a bit of research and I believe it means asymptotically equal to, but if that's true I still don't know how he arrived at this equation.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$\simeq$ here means "is approximately equal".
The second step uses
$$\left.\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right|_{x+dx}
 -\left.\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right|_{x}
\simeq \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}dx$$
which is just the definition of the second derivative
of a function $y(x)$.

From your calculus course you might be more familiar
with derivatives written using $'$ instead of
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.
Using this notation you can write the equation above
as well like this:

$$y'(x+dx)-y'(x) \simeq y''(x) dx$$
This approximate equation comes from
the definition of $y''(x)$:
$$y''(x)=\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{y'(x+dx)-y'(x)}{dx}$$